# javascript time event issue (setTimeout/clearTimeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout

I have always had trouble working with time events. Could someone please explain why A doesn't work and B does? The only difference is in A I put the event binding in a function. Don't worry about the function close, it has nothing to do with the question. When I test A, there is no js errors but timer is not cleared.

A ->

```
Test.Navigation = (function() {

    var openTimer = null;
    var closeTimer = null;

    var addListeners = function() {
        $('.hover_container').on('mousemove', function(e) {

            clearTimeout(closeTimer);

        });

        $('.hover_container').on('mouseleave', function(e) {

            // set the close timer
            var container = this; 
            closeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                //has the mouse paused
                close(container);
            }, 750);
        });

    };

    return {
        init : function() {
            addListeners();
        }
    };

})();
```

B ->

```
Test.Navigation = (function() {

    var openTimer = null;
    var closeTimer = null;

    $('.hover_container').on('mousemove', function(e) {

        clearTimeout(closeTimer);

    });

    $('.hover_container').on('mouseleave', function(e) {

        // set the close timer
        var container = this; 
        closeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            //has the mouse paused
            close(container);
        }, 750);
    });


    var addListeners = function() {
        // nothing here
    };

    return {
        init : function() {
            addListeners();
        }
    };

})();
```

Edit: Please ignore the container part, it has nothing to dow ith the question it is simply part of the full code that I did not take out

Comment: Use `setTimeout` for a single timing instance. Use `setInterval` for persistent timing.

Comment: Declare `var container = this;` in the direct scope of the container, not in another function. In **A**, container isn't what you need.

Comment: @dystroy container is what I need and that's beside the question, if the clear timer worked the close function would not fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is binded before the object exists where the init is called. Because your return a new object. If you are using, 2 objects are created. 1 with the vars en binds. and 1 with the returns.

B is working because you create a function where the elements are initialized and use the right scope. A is not working because the bindings are on the wrong scope because your create 2 objects:

```
new Test.Navigation(); // Create 1 object

// Create second object.
return {
    init : function() {
        addListeners();
    }
};
```

Youd better get a structure like this, then it should work aswell:

```
Test.Navigation = (function() {
    // Private vars. Use underscore to make it easy for yourself so they are private.
    var _openTimer = null,
        _closeTimer = null;

    $('.hover_container').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        clearTimeout(_closeTimer );
    });

    $('.hover_container').on('mouseleave', function(e) {

        // set the close timer, 
        //    use $.proxy so you don't need to create a exta var for the container.
        _closeTimer = setTimeout(
                $.proxy(function() {
                    //has the mouse paused
                    close(this);
                }, this)
            , 750);

    });


    this.addListeners = function() {
        // nothing here
    };

    this.init = function() {
        this.addListeners();
    }

    // Always call the init?
    this.init();

    return this; // Return the new object Test.Navigation
})();
```

And use it like

```
var nav = new Test.Navigation();
nav.init();
```

Also as you can see I upgraded your code a bit. Using `$.proxy`, `_` for private vars.

Comment: thank you for focusing on the question asked, explanation well understood

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `this` is in the wrong scope for the first approach.

Try

```
var openTimer = null;
var closeTimer = null;
var self = this;
```

and then later

```
var container = self;
```

In your code for example A,

```
$('.hover_container').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
 // set the close timer
 var container = this;
```

`this` is actually referring to the current `$('.hover_container')` element.

Also, since `setTimeout` will wait before the previous `setTimeout` finishes to start again, you can get discrepancies. You may want to switch to `setInterval` because it will issue its callback at every interval set regardless of if the previous callback has completed.

Comment: I get what you mean by the interval, but the container is exactly what I want to use because I want to close it, anyway that close function would not even fire if clear tie out was triggered correctly. Also, the container is the same in block A and B

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in the calling code, you have a statement `new Test.Navigation()` which, for B, addListeners is called at the time of new Test.Navigation().  In A, you return an object ref that calls an init function.  Can you verify that init() is called?

I.e. in A, init() has to be called before the handlers are added.  In B, the handlers are added everytime you instantiate Test.Navigation --- which, depending on the calling code, could be bad if you intend to instantiate more than one Test.Navigation() at a time.